# Error using IMAP in PHP?

Tags: php, email, imap

I was using the code,

```
<?php
 $mbox = imap_open("https://myserver.in", "developer@myserver.in", "123456", OP_HALFOPEN)
    or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$list = imap_getmailboxes($mbox, "https://myserver.in", "*");
if (is_array($list)) {
foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
    echo "($key) ";
    echo imap_utf7_decode($val->name) . ",";
    echo "'" . $val->delimiter . "',";
    echo $val->attributes . "<br />\n";
}
} else {
echo "imap_getmailboxes failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

but it is giving the error

```
Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream https://myserver.in in /home/myserver/public_html/vforms/mailtest.php on line 2
 can't connect: Can't open mailbox https://myserver.in: no such mailbox
```

The error is due to the parameter in imap_open() function, that i am not able to configure. so please help. Is there any PHP Class to fetch data from Inbox, and receive Email messages like PHPMailer Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at [the documentation](http://php.net/imap_open)? The mailbox address needs to be in a very specific format.

```
// To connect to an SSL IMAP or POP3 server, add /ssl after the protocol
// specification:
$mbox = imap_open ("{localhost:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "user_id", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

`https` != `imap`

So, probably it's something like

```
imap_open("{myserver.in:143}INBOX",...
```

Or:

```
imap_open("{myserver.in:993/imap/ssl}INBOX",...
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be most likely because of `openssl` extension since you are reading from the secure protocol that is `https`. Make sure that you have `openssl` extension turned on from php.ini.