# read mails from email account

Tags: php, email, imap

i want to read mails from a mail account.
In my outlook i can read the mails with no problem.
the settings in outlook are:
Type:IMAP
Server:sub.mailsvr.de
user:user1
pwd:pwd1
ports are standard

Now i want to read the inbox with php. 
My Code so far

```
$Mailkonto['imapopen'] == "{sub.mailsvr.de:143}INBOX";
$Mailkonto['user'] == "web15p13";
$Mailkonto['pwd'] == "PVDtqnKV";
$mbox = imap_open ($Mailkonto['imapopen'], $Mailkonto['user'], $Mailkonto['pwd']);
```

i get the following error

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(imap_errors());
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [0] => Can't open mailbox : no such mailbox
)
```

Has Somebody an idea, what i have to change to read the mails ?

Comment: does your email server use TLS Or SSL ? if so then you need to change port and configure for it. Also ensure your mail server have INBOX and it is sometime is case sensitive.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. But the problem is, thats not my email-server and the admin from that server is in holidays.

Comment: See if these solutions help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325150/error-using-imap-in-php

Comment: i tried all the solutions but nothing helped me. In my Outlook configuration is no SSL or any Port canged. There is the standard 143 an no specific SSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning any variables but using a boolean comparison without doing anything with the result:

```
$Mailkonto['imapopen'] == "{sub.mailsvr.de:143}INBOX";
$Mailkonto['user'] == "web15p13";
$Mailkonto['pwd'] == "PVDtqnKV";
```

Should be:

```
$Mailkonto['imapopen'] = "{sub.mailsvr.de:143}INBOX";
$Mailkonto['user'] = "web15p13";
$Mailkonto['pwd'] = "PVDtqnKV";
```